# How to combine Bootstrap Lightbox (ekko) JS file

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Hi I am trying to add [Bootstrap lightbox](https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox) to my bootstrap project and rather than including the js file in the header or footer I am trying to combine it with my existing js theme file. For some reason I can only get it to work on its own not when combined and minified. Has anyone encountered this? Any advice? Thanks

Using this theme in worpdress - https://github.com/holger1411/understrap

Files are combined with gulp